# Is it proper to place code, or content between the HTML </head> and <body> tags

Tags: html, header, standards, markup, head

Is it okay to place HTML code between the ending of the head area and before the beginning of the body area. I have done this before, on various sites without any problems, however, I would like to know whether this has any backwards compatibility issues, and also whether this is common, or good practice. For example:

```
</head>

   <div id="header">

       <h1>Heading</h1>

       Code & Content...

   </div><!-- #header -->

 <body>

    Code & Content...

 </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, is not okay. All the content of the page should go inside `<body>`. Check the [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/the-root-element.html#the-html-element).
Browsers are really forgiving, but even if it works you shouldn't do it.