# How is code *between* the end of the HEAD tag and before the BODY tag processed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have read [that it is bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911272/is-it-proper-to-place-code-or-content-between-the-html-head-and-body-tags) to do this, and outside the spec, but I have an error that is somewhat intermittent, and may be related.  Just want to know if the general consensus is "burn that code with napalm" or "it works, under these limited conditions".

I have found, in a very complex code base we maintain, `<script>` tags, both loading from external sources (javascript and jquery), and inline scripts, after the `</head>` and before the `<body>`.  Most of it is code that needs to load after the form is fully loaded.

Before I start making changes to incorporate the code into the bottom of the Head tag, I'd like to understand what is happening *right now* to clients that are running this code (the goal is to not break the current user experience).  Would these scripts be loaded before the page is rendered, or after?  What is the actual state of this no-man's-land code that shouldn't be there in the first place?

Thanks!

Comment: Browsers try their best to make sense out of broken code like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Content appearing between the `</head>` end tag and `<body>` start tag gets inserted just past the `<body>` start tag, unless it's an element that does not belong in the body, in which case it will be inserted at the end of the head.

Certain elements, like `script`, may appear in either the head or the body; script elements in that location will be inserted at the end of the head, *unless* the browser is already in the "in body" insertion mode, in which case they'll be placed in the body.

See sections [8.2.5.4.4 The "in head" insertion mode](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parsing-main-inhead), [8.2.5.4.6 The "after head" insertion mode](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#the-after-head-insertion-mode) and [8.2.5.4.7 The "in body" insertion mode](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parsing-main-inbody) of W3C HTML for further details. Note that implementations are not guaranteed to follow the spec, either owing to historical reasons, bugs, or deliberate decision to violate the spec, and this behavior should not be relied on.

Comment: So, any browser that is currently following the spec would treat these `<script>` blocks as occurring within and at the end of the `<head>` block.  Therefore, 1) Moving these scripts into the head should cause no problems, and 2) these out-of-place scripts likely aren't causing any problems at the moment anyway?

Comment: @Dan: If they don't already follow elements that would appear in body, yes. I haven't heard of any implementation that straight up refuses to run them, or runs them out of order, but I still wouldn't rely on it. Fix the markup errors if you are able, and test often.

Comment: Thanks for the links to the spec.  Interesting reading, and although a little hard to follow, any doc that tries to make sense of the rules to follow when parsing HTML is going to be challenging by nature.

Comment: @Dan: Good thing we're not browser developers.

Comment: Great answer! Simple and concise.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Yeah, that paragraph should have contained a link to the "after head" insertion mode. That said, the "in body" insertion mode does apply if the parser is already in that state (reached when encountering "Anything else" in "after head").

Comment: @BoltClock: I'm wrong anyway, "in head" applies. There's a higher-up rule with special handling for `script` and a few others. Your second paragraph gets it right, I believe.

Answer (score 7):

Fundamentally, it's invalid markup and a parsing error that the browser will have to recover from. So I would test this in your target browsers to see what they do.

In theory: After the closing `</head>` tag and before the opening `<body>` tag, the parser is in "['after head' insertion mode](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#the-after-head-insertion-mode)". I've listed the rules for that below, but thanks to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41879330/how-is-code-between-the-end-of-the-head-tag-and-before-the-body-tag-processed/41879427?noredirect=1#comment70941213_41879427), I think the relevant one is:

> - A start tag whose tag name is one of: "base", "basefont", "bgsound", "link", "meta", "noframes", "script", "style", "template", "title"
>
>   - Parse error.
>   - Push the node pointed to by the head element pointer onto the stack of open elements.
>   - Process the token using the rules for the "in head" insertion mode.
>   - Remove the node pointed to by the head element pointer from the stack of open elements. (It might not be the current node at this point.)
>   - The head element pointer cannot be null at this point.

Which tells us that:

1. It's a parsing error, see my opening paragraph. :-)
2. The spec seems to be telling the browser vendors to treat the script as though it were at the end of the `head`.

The full rules:

> When the user agent is to apply the rules for the "after head" insertion mode, the user agent must handle the token as follows:
>
> - A character token that is one of U+0009 CHARACTER TABULATION, "LF" (U+000A), "FF" (U+000C), "CR" (U+000D), or U+0020 SPACE
>
>   - Insert the character.
> - A comment token
>
>   - Insert a comment.
> - A DOCTYPE token
>
>   - Parse error. Ignore the token.
> - A start tag whose tag name is "html"
>
>   - Process the token using the rules for the "in body" insertion mode.
> - A start tag whose tag name is "body"
>
>   - Insert an HTML element for the token.
>   - Set the frameset-ok flag to "not ok".
>   - Switch the insertion mode to "in body".
> - A start tag whose tag name is "frameset"
>
>   - Insert an HTML element for the token.
>   - Switch the insertion mode to "in frameset".
> - A start tag whose tag name is one of: "base", "basefont", "bgsound", "link", "meta", "noframes", "script", "style", "template", "title"
>
>   - Parse error.
>   - Push the node pointed to by the head element pointer onto the stack of open elements.
>   - Process the token using the rules for the "in head" insertion mode.
>   - Remove the node pointed to by the head element pointer from the stack of open elements. (It might not be the current node at this point.)
>   - The head element pointer cannot be null at this point.
> - An end tag whose tag name is "template"
>
>   - Process the token using the rules for the "in head" insertion mode.
> - An end tag whose tag name is one of: "body", "html", "br"
>
>   - Act as described in the "anything else" entry below.
> - A start tag whose tag name is "head"
> - Any other end tag
>
>   - Parse error. Ignore the token.
> - Anything else
>
>   - Insert an HTML element for a "body" start tag token with no attributes.
>   - Switch the insertion mode to "in body".
>   - Reprocess the current token.

Comment: I can see why browser devs may disagree when reading this spec!

"A start tag whose tag name is one of: ..., "script", ...
Parse error.
Push the node pointed to by the head element pointer onto the stack of open elements.
Process the token using the rules for the "in head" insertion mode.
Remove the node pointed to by the head element pointer from the stack of open elements. (It might not be the current node at this point.)
The head element pointer cannot be null at this point."

This looks like it re-opens the head element, pushes the script into it, and closes the head again?

Comment: (sorry, I forgot that comments don't keep linefeeds)

Comment: @Dan: My conclusion is invalid, then, as I missed that rule! Fixed it, sorry.

Comment: Difficult to choose which is the "right" answer (accepted answer) because we all got to the same destination at the end.  I only chose @BoltClock because his is shorter to read to get to the essence of what I needed to know.

Comment: @Dan: In my view, for what it's worth, you made the right decision. (Not like you need my permission or blessing, but just the same...)