# Will having a different node than <body> and <head> under <html> invalidate the DOM?

Tags: html, dom

Have the following document :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>
    <head>  
        ...
    </head>
    <lml-templates>
        ...
    </lml-templates>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

We're currently using a `lml-template` custom element with a `{display: none}` style. This templating zone contains various wrappers meant to be used later by the web application to generate "normal" mark-up under `<body>`.

It contains user-defined mark-up used as templates for elements which will appear inside the body. We're using this method so that everything under the `<body>` tag is concrete where everything under `<lml-templates>` is abstract, but still queryable using `document.querySelector`.

Up until now, everything seems to be working fine, even on older-ish browsers.

According to [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_navigation.asp), it is said that head is the first child of html, and body its last. I however couldn't find any documentation about the "accepted" children nodes of `<html>` aside from those two little guys.

I know some browsers will fix incorrect markup such as `non-<li>` children of `<ul>`, but it never tried to fix our code whatsoever.

CSS also doesn't seem to care at all since the elements are still in the `DOM`. Styles like :

```
lml-template {
    display: none;
}
```

will work just fine. Nothing else under lml-template needs styling since it's invisible.

Should I be worried about this? Is it bad practice? Worst case, we'll simply move the templates under body, and wrap everything else inside a second wrapper like so :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>
    <head>  
        ...
    </head>

    <body>
        <lml-templates>
            ...
        </lml-templates>

        <div id="mainStage">
            ...
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But it pretty much destroys the entire idea behind our library. Hopefully this is not only a "Google more" question.

Google queries used without success :

- custom html child node
- accepted html child node
- html child node not body head
- valid dom html children node

Thanks.

EDIT:

Just noticed that Skimlinks' Chrome plugin (affiliate marketing partner) also uses the same method, and it seems to work. It's not like we can take for granted that because they use this method, it becomes a good practice, but it's interesting.

Again, their markup will actually become visible at fixed positions (`position: fixed;`). They probably don't want their elements to interact with the current document. Maybe?

[image: Skimlinks screenshot]

Comment: From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/html) : *Permitted content : One <head> element, followed by one <body> element.* From [WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-html-element) : *Content model:
    A head element followed by a body element.* Google query : *HTML element MDN* (which then links to the specs).

Comment: @Kaiido Interesting. Again, the "Content modal" is described as "A normative description of what content must be included as children and descendants of the element." This document contains both <head> and <body> elements. Not sure having additional tags makes the whole thing invalid--

Comment: It does. Every non `<head>` nor `<body>` tag set as direct children of an `<html>` one will make your HTML document invalid. But it doesn't mean browsers will crash, just that your document will be invalid. e.g Firefox does move everything in the `<body>` automagically.

Comment: @Érik Desjardins: When the content model says one head followed by one body, it means no additional elements are allowed. In fact, even one body followed by one head isn't allowed either, nor is just one head nor just one body.

Comment: @Érik Desjardins: If you're asking about validity in terms of the DOM tree representation of invalid markup, I'm not sure that can be measured in any meaningful way, since you're relying on invalid markup in the first place, even if the error recovery for said invalid markup is well-defined in the spec.

Comment: @BoltClock So basically, we're playing around with invalid markup, even if the DOM tree is still usable. Well, that is scary and definitely a bad programming practice. Alright, I'll let you answer the question if you want the accepted points, otherwise I'll answer it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-html-element):

> **Content model:**
>   A `head` element followed by a `body` element.

This means that the `html` element may *only* contain a `head` followed by a `body`, in that order, with no additional elements and both `head` and `body` must be there. (Their *tags* can be omitted for brevity, but the *elements* will still be generated in the DOM tree — one of the situations in which the distinction between tags and elements is important and why anyone who knows better will keep harping on it.)

If you're asking about validity in terms of the DOM tree representation of invalid markup, I'm not sure that can be measured in any meaningful way, since you're relying on invalid markup in the first place, even if the error recovery for said invalid markup is well-defined in the spec.

In fact, the spec does explain [how markup appearing between the `</head>` end tag and `<body>` start tag should be handled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41879330/how-is-code-between-the-end-of-the-head-tag-and-before-the-body-tag-processed), so the fact that Skimlinks seems to behave this way means Chrome knows something that we don't. Either way, it's certainly not something that should be relied on, since ultimately you're still working with invalid markup which is almost never good practice.

If you're interested in keeping your markup valid, I also recommend moving your element into `body` as its first child. That's exactly what the spec tells implementations to do, as revealed in the link above.