# Why .nextElementSibling doesn't return null?

Tags: javascript

In the below code, the `<div>` doesn't have any siblings.  `previousElementSibling` correctly returns `null`, but `nextElementSibling` does not.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>nextElementSibling</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>test</div>
</body>
<script>
    var demo = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
    console.log(demo.previousElementSibling);
    console.log(demo.nextElementSibling);
</script>
</html>
```

Console output:

[image]

Google Chrome Version 59.0.3071.86 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Why is this?

Comment: the question is `doesn't return`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because Chrome is being kind.

The `<script>` tag as positioned in your source code is not valid, so Chrome is automatically moving it into the `<body>`, where it is valid, and where it becomes the `nextElementSibling`.  If you inspect the loaded page, you see this:

[image]

Comment: "*Chrome is being kind*"..., [the rules are kind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41879369/3702797) Chrome follows the rules.

Comment: @Kaiido Fair point - that answer talks about between `<head>` and `<body>`, but I can well imagine that the rules are very similar for after `<body>` too.

Comment: The answer also talks about what happens when the parser is in the *in-body*, which is the last step/state

Comment: @Kaiido Sort of - just digging through now - it's actually gone into ["after body"](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parsing-main-afterbody), but the error handling step of that is to go back into "in body" again